# What would be the simplest analog of Langlands in algebraic topology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory, vector-bundles, langlands-conjectures, fundamental-group

It is oversimplified, I know, but just as a superficial analogy, one may think of the fact that abelianization of the fundamental group is the first homology group, as some remote relative of class field theory. To attempt increasing resemblance, one may dualize and speak about correspondence between characters/one dimensional representations of the fundamental group over some field and first cohomology with coefficients in the multiplicative group of that field; in sufficiently nice cases this should in particular give correspondence between appropriate brand of coverings, line bundles and their Chern classes. One may even try to imitate ramification by considering branched coverings and not necessarily locally free coherent sheaves or I don't know what (Question zero - has this actually been made more rigorous and if yes, where?).

I am not aware of any relevant higher-dimensional stuff, relating, say, 2-dimensional representations of the fundamental group to characteristic classes of the corresponding vector bundles in any context - say, over $\mathbb C$ even, let alone other coefficient fields or higher dimensional non-locally-free coherent sheaves. Are there any texts about this?

The question [What is the precise relationship between Langlands and Tannakian formalism?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/71743/41291) seems to be related but I am after something much more simple-minded

Comment: Just a remark (which you probably already know about): "abelianization of the fundamental group is the first homology group, as some remote relative of class field theory" is a statement used in the cohomological approach to class field theory.

Comment: @skd Well even that I am not sufficiently familiar with, and it would be great if you could put some detail in a sort of partial answer

Comment: Semi-related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7283/topological-langlands

Comment: @DrewHeard Many thanks for sharing this! It is very interesting, although WAY more sophisticated than what I am asking here.

Comment: The cohomological approach to class field theory is discussed in Milne's notes https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf; the essential idea is that $\mathrm{Gal}(K^\mathrm{ab}/K)$ can be thought of $\mathrm{H}_1(\mathrm{Gal}(K^\mathrm{sep}/K; \mathbf{Z})$, where $K$ is a nonarchimedean local field. In any case, I would say that Tate's theorem (II.3.11 in Milne) is the "most important" part of the proof, not this result. This is because Tate's theorem implies that if $L/K$ is a finite extension with Galois group $G$, then...

Comment: ...there is an isomorphism $\hat{\mathrm{H}}^{-2}(G; \mathbf{Z}) \to \hat{\mathrm{H}}^0(G; L^\times)$; the left hand side is $G_\mathrm{ab} = \mathrm{H}_1(G; \mathbf{Z})$, and the right hand side is $K^\times/\mathrm{N}(L^\times)$. This defines the local Artin homomorphism. Also: the link Drew pointed to is very relevant. I don't know anything about Langlands, but as far as I know (from high-level discussions with people) the n=2 case of Langlands is very closely related to the theory of modular forms. It should be no surprise that chromatic homotopy theory at height 2 also...

Comment: ... admits a deep relationship with the theory of modular forms (via the $\mathbf{E}_\infty$-ring of topological modular forms, and its numerous variants). Moreover, I've heard some people say that there should be a geometric interpretation of TMF cocycles in terms of "2-vector bundles", but I don't know what these are (this paper seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04146). tl;dr: the discussion in the link Drew provided probably isn't the simplest analogue of Langlands, but it definitely seems to be the "right" one.

Comment: @skd Thank you for bringing this up! I more and more think that I should start with a question about class field theory first. I believe the analog in algebraic topology of what you describe in the second part of your comment is actually a combination of some Poincaré-like duality (relating homology and cohomology) with something like connecting homomorphism for the exponential short exact sequence, relating cohomology with integer coefficients and shifted-by-one cohomology with circle group coefficients.

Comment: Would [arithmetic topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_topology) be useful to formulate such an analogue?

Comment: @Watson No idea. Do you have any specific circumstances in mind?